# Combine function for 10 digit phone number - no spaces

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

Been trying to validate with a 10 digit phone number, no spaces or any other characters other than numbers. I think I have the correct reg ex but am unsure how to implement the code so it works with NO spaces too.

**What I've done so far: Added in jquery.validationEngine-en.js**

```
// ADDED for 10 digit phone
"phone10": {
  "regex": /^[\d ]+$/, 
  // alertText brings up two error messages so using alertText2
  "alertText2": " numbers only: xxxxxxxxxx", 
},
```

**I then added the phone10 case statement in jquery.validationEngine.js:**

```
case "phone10":
  errorMsg = methods._getErrorMessage(form, field, rules[i], rules, i, 
    options, methods._phone10Size);
break;
```

**And put the function below called _phone10Size:**

```
_phone10Size: function(field, rules, i, options) {
  var max = rules[i + 1];
  var len = field.val().length;

  if (len < 10) {
    var rule = options.allrules.phone10;
    return 10 + rule.alertText2;
  }
},
```

Oh yeah, I've also had to put maxlength="10" on the form input field. I know it's not elegant or even "proper". Can someone tell me how to implement this 10 digits only that doesn't allow spaces? Thank you.

Comment: You have a space in the regex

Answer (score 7):

Figured out a solution for 10 numbers only (no spaces). For my class on the field I've put:

```
class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber],minSize[10],maxSize[10]] text-input"
```

and added the function OnlyNumber to line 97 in the jquery.validationEngine-en.js file:

```
"onlyNumber": {
    "regex": /^[0-9]+$/,
    "alertText": "* Numbers only"
 },
```

Comment: there is alerady function present for phone why did u need to add it
 "phone": {
                    // credit: jquery.h5validate.js / orefalo
                    "regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}([ \.\-])?)?([\(][0-9]{1,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-]{1,32})(([A-Za-z \:]{1,11})?[0-9]{1,4}?)$/,
                    "alertText": "* Invalid phone number"
                },

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default validate function inside jquery.validationEngine-en.js using 'number' example shown below :

```
class="validate[required,custom[number],minSize[10],maxSize[12]] text-input"
```

And you can use the phone function for the same as shown below:

```
class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input" type="text"
```